# flutter stripe deploying key to firebase cloud functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to deploy my stripe key to cloud functions and I am getting an error as follows(this is the last line from my debug log):

```
[debug] [2023-02-25T19:25:40.403Z] Error: Failed to create function createPaymentIntent in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:48:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Fabricator.createV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:177:32)
    at async Fabricator.createEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:129:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:85:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I do think I need to set the zone to somewhere on the east coast as I am in Toronto, Canada. How do I do that?

BTW here is the firebase command I issued (I just swapped the key instead of "YOUR KEY HERE"): `firebase functions:config:set stripe.testkey="YOUR KEY HERE"`

And this here is my index.ts file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

//firebase functions:config:set stripe.livekey="YOUR KEY HERE"
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey);

// // Start writing functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
// export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    stripe.paymentIntents.create(
        {
          amount: req.query.amount,
          currency: req.query.currency,
          payment_method: req.query.pm_id,
          confirmation_method: 'automatic',
          confirm: true,
          description: req.query.description,
        },
        function(err, paymentIntent) {
          // asynchronously called
          if (err !== null){
            console.log('Error payment Intent: ', err);
            res.send('error');} else {
            console.log('Created paymentintent: ', paymentIntent);
            res.json({
              paymentIntent: paymentIntent
        });
          }});
});
```

edit to add what I have just tried:

1. deleted the project and started over again, this time with just index.js instead of using type script.

This is my index.js file now:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("my key here");

exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'cad',
            customer: customerId,
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
[debug] [2023-02-26T01:29:11.314Z] Error: Failed to create function stripePaymentIntentRequest in region us-central1
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:48:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Fabricator.createV1Function (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:177:32)
    at async Fabricator.createEndpoint (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:129:13)
    at async handle (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:85:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have it running properly! Yay! Here is what I did:

1. delete the package-lock.json file

Then do the following in the index.js file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("YOUR SK LIVE KEY HERE");

//looks like deleting the lock file helped get this to work
exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.region('us-east4').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'cad',
            customer: customerId,
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of the stripe are you using in the package.json as dependency?